# Como acessar pagina de acordo com campo de texto input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Olá, tenho um campo de input no meu HTML, quero fazer com que dependendo do texto digitado, ela vá para pagina x ou y. Preciso também que dependendo, vá para uma página e nessa página mude o src de uma imagem para um caminho especifico.

Pensei em usar um javascript e pegar o valor inserido e mudar o valor de uma variavel, com isso fazer uma série de comparativos com ifs ou whiles e quando o valor for igual ao nome correto ela vai para a pagina x.

Sei que existem uma série de frameworks por aí que facilitariam o processo, mas sou novato e estou tentando dar um passo de cada vez.

OBS.: as páginas x e y são paginas dentro da pasta do projeto e não urls da internet.

Comment: A página x ou y diferem somente no `src` de uma imagem? ou há mais diferenças?

Comment: então, são páginas diferentes, com um body diferente. mas o head, css, javascript o msm.

Comment: queria algo tipo `if (var = sanduíche) {vai para pagina tal} else if (var = salamandra) {vai para outra página e nessa página mude a src da imagem para o caminho tal}` seria ótimo gravar essa variavel em cachê, e não em um banco de dados. visto que o msm site será usado por mais de uma pessoa, e preciso que operem independente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples de fazer com jQuery.

```js
function verificaValor(){
  var valor = $('#envia').val();
  if (valor == 'salamandra'){
    window.location.href = 'http://google.com/'
  } else if(valor == 'pitanguinha'){
    window.location.href = 'http://facebook.com';
  }
  else{
    $('#result').html('Insira um valor válido');
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="envia" placeholder="digite o valor">
  <input type="button" onclick="verificaValor()" value="envia">
</form>
<div id="result">
  
</div>
```